# writing a function that checks if tuples, lists and strings are sorted

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, tuples

I'm trying to build a function that prints true if the tuples, lists and strings inputted are sorted, and False if not. I've tried two different methods but neither worked.. Could anyone tell me what part is wrong? Thank you !!!

```
def is_ordered (*args):        
    for i in range(1,len(args)):
        if args[i - 1] > args[i]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
def is_ordered (*args):        
    if args == args.sorted()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here are the lists and tuples I created.

```
sorted_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
is_ordered(sorted_list)
unsorted_list = [41,3,35,4,45,6,7]
is_ordered(unsorted_list)
sorted_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
is_ordered(sorted_tuple)
unsorted_tuple = (41,3,35,4,45,6,7)
is_ordered(unsorted_tuple)
stri = "datascience"
is_ordered(stri)
```

Comment: your functions take _one_ argument, not multiple like the function signature suggest

Comment: your function also *returns immediately* on the first iteration

Comment: Why are you using `*args` instead of a regular parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to sort the input to tell if it's sorted. You just need to see if each item is less than or equal to the item before it and return False if that's ever not the case. This will be more efficient than sorting, then checking.

You can compare items with the neighbor by zipping the list with itself at an offset like `zip(seq, seq[1:]`.

```
def is_ordered (seq):
    '''Return true if every item is less than or equal the item after it'''
    return all(a <= b for a, b in zip(seq, seq[1:]))

is_ordered('abcd')
#True

is_ordered('abdag')
#False

is_ordered([1, 2, 3, 4])
#True
```

If you *want* to use `sorted()`, don't use `*args` just accept a sequence as an argument and understand that `sorted(someString)` will not equal a string because it makes a list. So you need to compare like things:

```
def is_ordered (seq):
    return list(seq) == sorted(seq)

is_ordered((1, 2, 3))
#True

is_ordered((1, 2, 3, 0))
#False

is_ordered("abcd")
# True

is_ordered("abcda")
# False
```

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your response! This is for a basic entry level data science class. I'm wondering if it's able to do it without zip (it's too advanced we haven't learned about it yet.. THank you!

Comment: @GraceWang see the edit for using `sorted()` (Also, zip() is fundamental python — it's  worth learning early because it comes up a lot)

Comment: Thank you so much Mark This was really helpful!!